# Non-collapsed Alexandrov spaces, level surface of regular map homeo to its lifting?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, alexandrov-geometry

Let $X_i$ be n dimensional,  no boundary Alexandrov spaces with curvature $\geqslant -1$ and diameter $\leqslant D$.  Suppose that $X_i$ converge to an n dimensional Alexandrov space $X$. Then by Perelman's stability theorem, for i large, $X_i$ are homeomorphic to $X$.

Suppose $f:U\to R^m$ is regular on an open subset $U\subset X$, using approximation map $X\to X_i$, we can define a regular map $f_i:U_i\to R^m$. For $c\in R^m$, consider the level surfaces $f^{-1}(c), f_i^{-1}(c)$ with intrinsic metric, **is $f_i^{-1}(c)$ homeomorphic to $f^{-1}(c)$ for i large?**

A version of Stability theorem says that: there exists a homeomorphism $h_i: X\to X_i$ such that $f_i \circ h_i=f$ holds on every compact set $K\subset U$ and sufficiently large i.  Then we have $h_i(f^{-1}(c))=f_i^{-1}(c)$. Since the intrinsic metrics of $f^{-1}(c), f_i^{-1}(c)$ are equivalent to the extrinsic metrics up to a constant, so $h_i$ is a homeomorphism from $f^{-1}(c)$ to $f_i^{-1}(c)$?

Comment: The strongest version of stability theorem is given here https://anton-petrunin.github.io/papers/alexandrov/perelmanASWCBFB2+.pdf. If I remember correctly, the statement you are looking for is there. (In the published paper Perelman simplified the proof, but made statements less general.)

Comment: @AntonPetrunin: The definition of regular map in Perelman's paper Alexandrov II is weaker than Elements of Morse theory. In Alexandrov II, for sets $A_i$, $\angle (A_i')_p, (A_j')_p >\frac{\pi}{2}-\delta$ and there is $\xi_p \in \Sigma_p$ such that $\angle (A_i')_p, \xi_p >\frac{\pi}{2}+\epsilon$. Let $f=(dist(A_1,\cdot),...)$, So you mean for i large, the level sets $f_i^{-1}(c)$ is homeomorphic to $f_i^{-1}(c)$?